# Вставить кнопку и функцию, которая будет закрывать окно

Tags: jquery, ajax

Помогите вставить кнопку и функцию, которая будет закрывать это окно.
Закрытие окна должно происходить после того, как нажмется текст "Продолжить покупки"

```
$('#button-cart').bind('click', function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('.product-info input[type=\'text\'], .product-info input[type=\'hidden\'], .product-info input[type=\'radio\']:checked, .product-info input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, .product-info select, .product-info textarea'),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            $('.success, .warning, .attention, information, .error').remove();

            if (json['error']) {
                if (json['error']['option']) {
                    for (i in json['error']['option']) {
                        $('#option-' + i).after('<span class="error">' + json['error']['option'][i] + '</span>');
                    }
                }
            }

            if (json['success']) {

                $('#notification').html('<div class="layer">&nbsp;</div><div class="addtocart_window"><div class="c"><div class="t">Товар добавлен в корзину</div><a class="btn btn-default btn-subscribe" href="/cart_items/" title="Оформить заказ">Оформить заказ</a><br><br><span class="t2 close2">Продолжить покупки</span></div></div>');

                $('.success').fadeIn('slow');

                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow'); 
            }

        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понял вся проблем в том, что не получается повесить событие Click на динамически создаваемый <span>?

```
$('#notification').html('<div class="layer">&nbsp;</div><div class="addtocart_window"><div class="c"><div class="t">Товар добавлен в корзину</div><a class="btn btn-default btn-subscribe" href="/cart_items/" title="Оформить заказ">Оформить заказ</a><br><br><span class="t2 close2">Продолжить покупки</span></div></div>');
```

кажется должно быть так, сразу на след строчке.
    $("span.close2").on("click",function(){closeFn();});

Не?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась вот этим кодом:

```
$('#notification').on('click', '.close2', function(){ 
     $(this).closest('#notification').empty().hide();
});
```